# iText PDF font change does not happen. Rupee symbol not getting displayed

Tags: java, android, pdf, fonts, itext

I am using iText PDF to create PDF files in android. I need to write the '₹' symbol in the PDF.
I have the following code:-

```
public static final String FONT1 = "/main/assets//PlayfairDisplay-Regular.ttf";
public static final String FONT2 = "/main/assets/PT_Sans-Web-Regular.ttf";
public static final String FONT3 = "/main/assets/FreeSans.ttf";
public static final String RUPEE = "The Rupee character \u20B9 and the Rupee symbol \u20A8";
```

These are declared as class variables.
I have a function createPDF() which writes to the PDF document.
I have the following lines of code in the function:-

```
    File pdfFile = new File(filePath);
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(pdfFile);
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, output);
    document.open();
    Font f1 = FontFactory.getFont(FONT1, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, 12);
    Font f2 = FontFactory.getFont(FONT2, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, 12);
    Font f3 = FontFactory.getFont(FONT3, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, 12);
    Font f4 = FontFactory.getFont(FONT3, BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, 12);
    document.add(new Paragraph(RUPEE, f1));
    document.add(new Paragraph(RUPEE, f2));
    document.add(new Paragraph(RUPEE, f3));
    document.add(new Paragraph(RUPEE, f4));
    document.close();
```

However neither the font gets reflected in the PDF nor the Rupee Symbol.
My PDF looks as below:-

[image: Resulting PDF]

I have followed steps using the below links:-
[iText Developers Tutorial](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/font-examples/showing-special-characters#897-rupeesymbol.java)
and [StackOverflow Question on where to place Assets folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302603/where-to-place-assets-folder-in-android-studio)

I am aware of another similar question on SO:-
[Rupee symbol is not showing in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26360814/rupee-symbol-is-not-showing-in-android/26362801#26362801)
however this also has not helped me.

Am I doing anything wrong here ? Are my fonts placed in the wrong location?

Comment: The path to your fonts is wrong. How do I know? All the text shown in your PDF is in Helvetica (which is the default font).

Comment: Try,remove all /main/ just keep like assets/PlayfairDisplay-Regular.ttf so on... and in the first font you have // remove that one too and try

Comment: @BrunoLowagie . Thanks that helped :)

Comment: @Raghavendra thanks for that. That helped. :) Silly from my side.

Comment: @Raghavendra Please make that an actual answer Pratik can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,
Remove all /main/ just keep like assets/PlayfairDisplay-Regular.ttf so on... and in the first font you have // remove that one too and try