# display indian rupee character in an iText PDF

Tags: google-app-engine, itext

I want to display Indian Rupee character on an iText PDF. I'm working with GAE Eclipse plugins and using default encoding-Cp1252. I've tried other answers, but no luck so far.

Comment: As you are working on GAE, the same rules as defined for Android apply: you need to use iTextG because iTextG is iText for Android and GAE. Hence the question is identical to [Rupee symbol is not showing in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26360814/rupee-symbol-is-not-showing-in-android). The main problem is usually a missing font. As you can tell from the answer to the duplicate question not all fonts contain the Rupee character. Your problem is that you use CP1252 (aka Winansi) and as documented that encoding doesn't know anything about the Rupee character.

Comment: See the [Cp1252 table on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), do you see the Rupee character anywhere? Also check the encodings that support it: [20b9](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20b9/charset_support.htm) and you won't find Cp1252. If we look at another character, e.g. the non-breaking space character, we see many more encodings: [00a0](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/charset_support.htm)