# How to add rupee symbol as prefix in iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, symbols, prefix

Is it possible to add **rupee symbol** as currency prefix to an amount in itextsharp PDF.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. 

what have you ***tried yourself*** so far? what problems did you encounter? what have you researched? i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17470300/1729265) help?

Comment: Great! I closed your question as duplicate of that other question.